# Why does Gmail mark some messages read and some unread in my Spam folder?

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention

I use Gmail which has tremendous spam filtering capabilities.

But, I'm curious why some messages are marked read vs. some left unread in the Spam label folder.

Of my 1,000 current messages in Spam, most ( 900+ ) are marked as read. BUT, there are some scattered throughout that are bold (Unread).

I couldn't find any helpful information in the Gmail docs. My best guess is that Gmail marks as read those messages that it *knows* are Spam, and leaves un-read those messages that it isn't 100% sure are spam.

Does anyone have any idea why some Spam messages are read and some unread?

Comment: do you have any filters that might mark something "read" using a keyword?

Comment: @Logman you should put this as an answer so I can accept – I did have a filter in place (must be years old because I don't recall creating it) which marked as read any messages that did not contain my name or company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your GMail filters, there might be a filter(s) that mark something "read" using a keyword.